# Display custom field on 404 page outside loop

Tags: php, custom-field, page-template

I'm using ACF to display a class within a `<header>` tag. The code for this sits within header.php. The custom field appears across all page templates in WP admin. Here's how it's working on the front-end:

```
<header 
    class="site-header 
    <?php
        $header = get_field( 'header',$post->ID );
        if ($header) { 
            echo esc_attr( $header ); 
        } 
        else { 
            echo 'white';
        }
    ?>" 
>
```

This works perfectly on all pages apart from the 404. I'm receiving the following message within dev tools:

```
<header class="site-header <br /> <b>Notice</b>: Trying to get property of non-object in <b>/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/theme/wp-content/themes/theme/header.php</b> on line <b>28</b><br /> white">
</header>
```

This is happening because the 404 is a static page / post and does not have an ID associated to it.

Is there a function within WordPress I can use to display my custom field properly?

Comment: You get a 404 if **there is no `$post`**.

Comment: Makes sense. Is there a parameter I can pass for non posts?

Comment: I don't know. `get_field()` is not a WordPress function. Ask the ACF support.

Comment: I've edited my question and have found a solution. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not hide functionality in a template file. Templates are dumb, you don't run unit tests on them normally.

I'd recommend to move the logic to a separate function in your `functions.php`:

```
function header_class( $default= 'white' )
{
    $post = get_post();

    // 404 pages, empty archives (user, taxonomy, date)
    if ( empty( $post ) )
        return $default;

    $header = get_field( 'header', $post->ID );

    if ( empty( $header ) || ! is_scalar( $header ) )
        return $default;

    return esc_attr( $header );
}
```

And in your template you can now just call the function:

```
<header id="masthead" class="site-header <?= header_class() ?>" role="banner">
```

Comment: Nice solution, thanks. I'll start using this for future projects.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [is 404](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_404) function to resolve this issue. The following worked for me:

```
<header id="masthead" class="site-header 

    <?php

        if ( is_404() ) {
            echo 'white';
        }

        else {

            $header = get_field( 'header',$post->ID );

            if ( $header ) { 
                echo esc_attr( $header ); 

            } 

            else { 
                echo 'white';
            }
        }

    ?>"

role="banner">
```